# 共有SSLの301リダイレクトについてご教授下さい

Tags: ssl

サイト移転で困っていることがあります。
皆さまご教授下さい。

旧サイトはロリポップレンタルサーバーにて契約をしていました。
SSLは共有SSLのため、URLがロリポップレンタルサーバーのURLに変更されています。

ttp://oldsite.com/free.htmlとあると
ロリポップのＳＳＬページが
ttps://lolipop-oldsite.ssl-lolipop.jp/free.htmlといった感じに変換されてしまいます。

かなり前から運営を行なっていて、知識もまだなかった私はURLの正規化も知らずに当時から正規化をしていなかった為、それが今現在重複コンテンツと判断されてしまっています。

今はカノニカルで共有SSLのURLを非SSLのhtmlファイルから各ページに指定してやってます。
サーチコンソールにて、サイトアドレス変更処理を両方のURLから新サイトに向けて処理している感じです。

なので、当然ですが、検索順位も不安定な動きをします。

301リダイレクトなのですが、前述のようなURL/ドメイン自体が変わってしまう場合はどのように記述してやればよいのでしょうか？

通常の[http]から[https]へリダイレクトという記述とは異なりますよね？

皆さま宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: URL頭のhを削除しているのはわざとでしょうか？それともそうなってしまうということでしょうか？リンクをわざと非リンクにする必要はありません。どうしても行いたいのであればコードブロックを利用するかバッククォート(`)で括ってください。

Comment: 例示用ドメイン「example.com」というものがあるので、質問文に利用しやすいです。

Comment: お困りなのは伝わってきたんですが、何が達成できれば良いのかがよくわかりませんでした。旧サイトへのアクセスを新サイトに301リダイレクトしたいということで合ってますか？